# lsusb missing output

Tags: command-line, 20.04, usb

I use to get detailed output with `lsusb`. However, the output since recently is being displayed in the following format without any descriptive string(s) which is strange:

```
$ lsusb
1d6b:0003 (bus 2, device 1)
13d3:56a6 (bus 1, device 4) path: 6
8087:0025 (bus 1, device 3) path: 5
09da:2403 (bus 1, device 2) path: 4
1d6b:0002 (bus 1, device 1)
```

Did something accidentally changed/deleted which could've lead up to output shown above?
Thanks in advance for any help and insights

Comment: Only you would know what you have changed and or deleted.

Comment: Try `lsusb -v` that will increase verbosity. Perhaps you previously had an alias that added the -v automatically

Comment: The mapping between numerical IDs and human-readable device descriptions relies on the file `/var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids` I think - is that file present on your system?

Comment: yes the file is indeed present. I can't think of any reason as why `lsusb` all of a sudden changed its output format.

Comment: @PonJar I checked with `lsusb -v` and still the same output.

Comment: ... actually it looks like `/var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids` may no longer be relevant: `lsusb` appears to read the information from `/run/udev/data` which in turn appears to be populated from `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-usb-vendor-model.hwdb`

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the default `lsusb` utility from `usbutils` package was overridden in the path variable with another `lsusb` utility from [apio](https://pypi.org/project/apio/) package, which i installed a couple of days ago. Falling back onto `/usr/bin/lsusb` restored the actual output.